# Using service accounts across projects in GCP with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp

I have multiple projects in my GCP.
So, for Project A I have created a service account and I am using this service account for Project B using IAM roles and creating various infrastructures.

I am creating these resources using terraform scripts.
As terraform needs service account credentials, I have generated the same key ring JSON file from the Project A and provide in the terraform variable.

The issues occurs when I am creating a Cloud Build Trigger in Project B using terraform, it says it doesn't have enough permissions to create the same, but I have provided all the necessary permissons to do so.
The weird thing what I found that, on the terraform error, it points out to the Project A instead of Project B and i.e. why I am experiencing this error.
The service account key contains project id as well as the the service account name, which in my case is Project A, and that's what creating the issue here.

So, is there any solution for the same, so either in any way I can replace the values in JSON file with the values provided in the scripts.

Comment: Can you share the terraform code pls ?

Comment: 1/ Can you provide code, please? 2/ if you work within GCP boundaries, it is highly unlikely you need any key - everythin should work through IAM role granting.

Comment: @al-dann is correct, it's very likely you need not share keys. A nuance is that a Service Account is **owned** by a Google Project. This differs from user accounts which are not owned by any one Google Projects. To permit a Service (or user) Account on **any** Google resource (Project or other), you must bind the Account to the resource with a(n IAM) role. It is very likely that you have not correctly bound the Service Account (owned by Project A) to Project B with a [Cloud Build IAM role](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/iam-roles-permissions#predefined_roles).

Comment: **but I have provided all the necessary permissons to do so**. Edit your question with those permissions (IAM Roles) for each project.